# htaccess no redirecciona de url amigable a el archivo que le corresponde

Tags: .htaccess, docker, proxy

Tengo la siguiente url amigable:

```
dominio/install
```

Yo esperaba que a partir de esta url el sistema evaluara si existe el archivo `php` correspondiente con la siguiente configuración en el archivo `.htaccess`:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^.*setup.*\$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /setup.php [L,R=301]

</IfModule>
```

Pero no funciona he deshabilitado todo el cache de por medio y simplemente no funciona envía: error 404 not found.

El objetivo era poder mostrar la url amigable y al mismo tiempo redirigir los request al archivo `setup.php`

**Update:**

La cosa es más compleja de lo que esperaba, el error no esta en el `.htaccess` ya que he realizado una validacion más simple y utilizar un stack LAMP laragon con la siguiente configuracion `vhost + nginx proxy reverse` y me funciona:

***vhost***

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>
    DocumentRoot "C:/wnunez/Entertaiment/Desarrollo/Web/LH2/public/"
    ServerName lh-2.me
    ServerAlias *.lh-2.me
    <Directory "C:/wnunez/Entertaiment/Desarrollo/Web/LH2/public/">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

***Proxy reverse laragon***

```
server {
    server_name lh-2.me;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://lh-2.me:8080;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_cache off;
    }
}
```

La situación es que ***NO*** es este el entorno que quiero utilizar; ya que estaría haciendo todo en Windows y la idea era poder hacer el desarrollo desde una plataforma tipo Linux.

***Antes de ser juzgado por la aberración que voy a explicar; les pido que tengan en cuenta que es un mal necesario ya que tengo diferentes desarrollos en procesos y no puedo utilizar una configuración más simple.***

1. Tengo alrededor de 3 proyectos que puedo desarrollar en mi entorno Windows pero que ejecutan diferentes versiones de php; por eso tengo instalado `Laragon` del cual utilizo nginx como proxy reverso el cual esta activamente escuchando en el puerto 80.
2. Tengo Apache (Laragon) en el puerto 8080; con los 3 proyectos corriendo sobre 3 virtual host los cuales ejecutan php 5.6, php 7.2 y php 7.4, sin ningún problema.
3. resulta que ahora tengo este desarrollo (el cuarto) el cual me han pedido que despliegue con DOCKER y que este implementa php8.1
4. Para lograr ese objetivo intermedio se me ocurrió la grandiosa idea de meterle al DOCKER otro proxy reverso nginx que escucha en el puerto 8081 para darle acceso a cualquier proyecto que dependa de docker:

***Problema:***

He logrado que el proxy reverso de Laragon se vea con el proxy reverso de Docker; pero al querer implementar las URL amigables simplemente no funciona y no hay rastro en los logs de cuál es el error.

***Mi setup del proxy reverso en Windows + el entorno de desarrollo en docker***

host de windows:

```
127.0.0.1    www.lh-2.dock      lh-2.dock      #para el acceso a el server web en docker
127.0.0.1    www.lh-2.pma.dock  lh-2.pma.dock  #para el acceso a el  phpmyadmin en docker
```

Configuración proxy reverso laragon (Windows) aquí comienza la magia, con esto logro que cualquier acceso en el navegador de Windows a la url lh-2.dock sea re-direccionada al proxy reverso de docker que se encuentra a la escucha en: http://localhost:8081/

```
server {
    server_name lh-2.dock;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8081;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_cache off;
    }
}
server {
    server_name lh-2.pma.dock;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8081;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_cache off;
    }
}
```

Entonces el setup de docker que estoy utilizando para recibir la peticion y el servidor apache+php en docker:

```
version: "3.9"

services:
  reverse-proxy:
    container_name: LH-2-Proxy-Server
    image: jwilder/nginx-proxy
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro
    ports:
      - "8081:80"
    networks:
      - lamp-network
    extra_hosts:
      - "lh-2.dock:127.0.0.1"
      - "lh-2.pma.dock:127.0.0.1"
  webserver:
    container_name: LH-2-Web-Server
    build:
      context: ./bin/php81
    restart: always
    expose:
      - 80
    ports:
      - "8082:80"
    networks:
      - lamp-network
    depends_on:
      - database
    volumes:
      - ./../:/var/www/html:rw
      - ./../public:/var/www/html/public:rw
      - ./config/vhosts:/etc/apache2/sites-enabled
      - ./config/php/php.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/php.ini
      - ./logs/apache2:/var/log/apache2
    environment:
      VIRTUAL_HOST: "lh-2.dock"
      APACHE_DOCUMENT_ROOT: "/var/www/html/"
    extra_hosts:
      - "host.docker.internal:host-gateway"
  database:
    build:
      context: ./bin/mysql8
    container_name: LH-2-mysql8
    restart: always
    networks:
      - lamp-network
    ports:
      - "127.0.0.1:3307:3307"
    volumes:
      - ./config/initdb:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
      - ./data/mysql:/var/lib/mysql
      - ./logs/mysql:/var/log/mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: "********"
      MYSQL_DATABASE: "lh-2"
      MYSQL_USER: "********"
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: "********"
  phpmyadmin:
    container_name: LH-2-phpmyadmin
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - database
    environment:
      VIRTUAL_HOST: "lh-2.pma.dock"
      PMA_HOST: "database"
      PMA_PORT: "3306"
      PMA_USER: "********"
      PMA_PASSWORD: "********"
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: "********"
      MYSQL_USER: "********"
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: "********"
      UPLOAD_LIMIT: 512M
      MEMORY_LIMIT: 512M
    volumes:
      - /sessions
      - ./config/php/php.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/php-phpmyadmin.ini
    networks:
      - lamp-network
networks:
  lamp-network:
    driver: bridge
```

y por ultimo entonces el virtual host dentro de mi contenedor  `webserver: container_name: LH-2-Web-Server`:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName lh-2.dock
    ServerAlias *.lh-2.dock
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/public/"
    <Directory "/var/www/html/public/">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Se supone que agregando `AllowOverride All` deberia haber solucionado el problema pero al final no funciona XD ... y estoy asumiendo que es por toda la trama que estoy implementando.

Errores en los logs de los contenedores:

***Apache:***

> [Sat Aug 26 23:19:34.168174 2023] [negotiation:error] [pid 20] [client
> 172.18.0.2:57922] AH00687: Negotiation: discovered file(s) matching request: /var/www/html/public/setup (None could be negotiated).

***other_vhost_access.log***

> lh-2.dck:80 172.18.0.2 - - [26/Aug/2023:23:19:34 +0000] "GET /setup
> HTTP/1.1" 404 450 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64)
> AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/116.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"

Esquema de trabajo de los proxys y tecnología implementadas:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: tenes configurado y habilitado el mod_rewrite?????

Comment: @John si, pero el problema ya lo enconre el problema es que no se como solucionarlo por que hay muchas tramas mescladas.

Answer (score 1):

entiendo y no es una aberración, yo mismo he usado muchos proyectos en un entorno con proxy reverso, pero nunca o ahora que lo pienso en una ves ocupe nginx, siempre ocupo el mismo apache de server inverso

lo que hago lo tratare de explicar.

tienes 3 proyectos un phpmyadmin y un proxy.

explicación general

se crea una sub red en este caso 172.4.0.X
y cada servidor en ella se puede comunicar entre ellos
luego solo el proxy tiene un puerto del 80 local al 80 de tu maquina, por lo que solo el proxy es accesible desde 127.0.0.1:80
esa es la idea, asi puedes navegar en los proyectos usando los dominios en tu server DNS o archivo hosts

```
127.0.0.1 proyecto1.com
127.0.0.1 proyecto2.com
127.0.0.1 proyecto3.com
127.0.0.1 phpmyadmin.com
```

ejemplo de .yml

```
version: '3.5'
services:
  proyecto1:
    container_name: proyecto1
    image: php:5.6
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true   
    privileged: true
    volumes:
      - ./proyecto1/:/var/www/html
    networks:
      app-network_localnet:
        ipv4_address: 172.4.0.2

  proyecto2:
    container_name: proyecto2
    image: php:7.4
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true   
    privileged: true
    volumes:
      - ./proyecto2/:/var/www/html
    networks:
      app-network_localnet:
        ipv4_address: 172.4.0.3

  proyecto3:
    container_name: proyecto3
    image: php:8.2
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true   
    privileged: true
    volumes:
      - ./proyecto3/:/var/www/html
    networks:
      app-network_localnet:
        ipv4_address: 172.4.0.4

  proyectos_proxy:
    container_name: proyectos_proxy
    image: ubuntu/apache2:2.4-20.04_beta
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true   
    privileged: true
    ports:
      - '80:80'
    networks:
      app-network_localnet:
        ipv4_address: 172.4.0.5

  proyectos_phpmyadmin:
    container_name: proyectos_phpmyadmin
    image: phpmyadmin:latest
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true   
    privileged: true
    volumes:
      - ./proyecto1/:/var/www/html
    networks:
      app-network_localnet:
        ipv4_address: 172.4.0.6


#Docker Networks fijas para el proxy
networks:
  app-network_localnet:
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
      driver: default
      config:
        - subnet: 172.4.0.0/24
```

ejemplo de http.conf del proxy

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

ServerName proyecto1.com
ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyPass /  http://172.4.0.2/
ProxyPassReverse / http://172.4.0.2/

ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/proyecto1_error_log
CustomLog /var/log/apache2/proyecto1_access_log combined

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>

ServerName proyecto2.com
ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyPass /  http://172.4.0.3/
ProxyPassReverse / http://172.4.0.3/

ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/proyecto2_error_log
CustomLog /var/log/apache2/proyecto2_access_log combined

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>

ServerName proyecto3.com
ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyPass /  http://172.4.0.4/
ProxyPassReverse / http://172.4.0.4/

ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/proyecto3_error_log
CustomLog /var/log/apache2/proyecto3_access_log combined

</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost *:80>

ServerName phpmyadmin.com
ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyPass /  http://172.4.0.6/
ProxyPassReverse / http://172.4.0.6/

ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/phpmyadmin_error_log
CustomLog /var/log/apache2/phpmyadmin_access_log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

al final es un poco largo, espero lo puedas entender, una ves que lo entiendes es simple.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

como nota te hago ver que cuando usas un proxy inverso no puedes llamar al host por localhost si tu server se llama lh-2.dock ya que jamas lo encontrará
tu virtual host o almenos el que estas llamando no es este

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName lh-2.dock
    ServerAlias *.lh-2.dock
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/public/"
    <Directory "/var/www/html/public/">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

sino que estas llamando al virtalhost de http.conf o el default asi que tu .htaccess esta bien, lo que esta mal es la forma de llamarlo

Comment: pues si me funciona por que a diferencia de usar direcciones ip, en mi yml en el proxy declaro los dominios locales, que a su vez declaro como host virtuales; el problema no es el acceso a los servicios , el problema es unicamente con las url amigables al final, el problema si es con las url, pero lo que hace complejo la resolucion es la trama de los proxy's